# Как передать дополнительные параметры в handleClick()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

По кнопке мне нужно активировать функцию, передав в нее какое то значение, но обработка клика обязательно хочет принять "синтетическое событие - е". Если я передаю что то кроме этого события, событие пропадает. Хочу примерно то, что ниже.

```
function handleClick(e, value) {
e.preventDefault();}

<button onClick={handleClick(e, value)}>button</button>
```

Comment: `<button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, value)}>`, [документация](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: @nörbörnën благодарю, все работает, добавьте ответ, плюсану

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для передачи дополнительный параметров в обработчик события нужно делать так:

```
const Compoment = () => {
  const handleClick = (ev, additional_param) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('handleClick ', additional_param);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={(ev) => handleClick(ev, 'hello')}>button</button>
  );
};
```

Подробнее про обработку событий в React-элементах написано в [документации](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).